# Careers does not display year in account info

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, jobs

A screenshot of my `file cv` tab on Careers:

[image: If image is missing, leave a comment]

Years are missing from the dates.  I using Chrome to access the site and my browser locale is set to **`en-GB`**.

Comment: Mine says `Mmm d 'yy at HH:MM`, in both en-gb and en-us, so it's probably an off-by-one error in the calculation where it determines whether it should display the year or not.

Answer (score 2):

There was logic in place that showed you the year if the date in question was more than 11 months in the past. As subscriptions run a year (not counting lifetime subscriptions) it should be clear what year the respective dates are in, unless you get too close to the start date in the current year.

That said, we've tweaked the logic a bit, so now the year will show if the date is in a different calendar year than the current date (or more than 11 months old for those people that subscribed in January and are checking in on their subscription status in December).

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like that (dealing with subscriptions), I would think that you'd want it to *always* show the year.